# How to convert a nested list of keys to a dummies-like dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to convert following list to a pandas dataframe?

```
my_list = [["A","B","C"],["A","B","D"]]
```

And as an output  I would like to have a dataframe like:

| Index | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: I conduct some web scraping operations. Therefore I need to convert some unstructured data to structured ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can craft Series and concatenate them:

```
my_list = [["A","B","C"],["A","B","D"]]

df = (pd.concat([pd.Series(1, index=l, name=i+1)
                for i,l in enumerate(my_list)], axis=1)
        .T
        .fillna(0, downcast='infer') # optional
      )
```

or with [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(my_list))
df = df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_', 1).str[-1], axis=1).max()
```

output:

```
   A  B  C  D
1  1  1  1  0
2  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: The OP's desired output includes the column name "Index" for the first column. Could you edit your answer to include that as well?

Comment: @cigien in my case this is an index, not a column. But you could add `.reset_index()` to have an "index" column, or `.rename_axis('XXX').reset_index()` for a custom name.

Comment: @cigien what brought you and Tyler to this question? I'm just curious.

Comment: @richardec What makes me curious is why this question was **so** unpopular. It could have been more explicit but remained however interesting.

Comment: Agreed, @mozway. Probably something about it caused it to be automatically linked in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), where several folks came and took a look.

Answer (score -2):

I'm unsure how those two structures relate. The my_list is a list of two lists containing ["A","B","C"] and ["A", "B","D"].

If you want a data frame like the table you have, I would suggest making a dictionary of the values first, then converting it into a pandas dataframe.

```
my_dict = {"A":[1,1], "B":[1,1], "C": [1,0], "D":[0,1]}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(my_df)
```

Output:

[image: Output]